# Why does observe() not execute synchronously on the server?

Tags: meteor

When inserting (updating, removing, ...) to a collection on the client, then local observers will fire synchronously, i.e. while locally simulating the effect of the insertion. This means that subsequent code can rely on all side-effects of the insertion without race conditions.

The behavior on the server seems to be different: observers seem to trigger asynchronously and the insert callback may return before observers have been executed. This makes it more difficult to properly synchronize code: I couldn't find a reliable method to tell when all side-effects of the insertion have taken place. Other than on the client, this creates a race condition when relying on side-effects directly after the insert operation and it becomes more difficult to share code between client and server.

Is this intended behavior? Is there a good workaround on the server side to tell when all observers have executed?

(My use case: I have a "commands" table which I need for undo/redo. Inserting a new command will trigger changes to local, non-synchronized collections, i.e. the command is being executed from within an observer. Subsequent commands require the changes to local collections to be complete, otherwise they'll fail.)

Comment: This is the latency compensation kicking into action. To avoid it you could use a `Meteor.call` and `Meteor.methods`. If the client/server don't sync for some reason the operation reverses on the client end and it throws an error on the callback. I also asked something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800971/meteor-latency-compensation-and-hinting-completion-commit-to-the-user

Comment: @Akshat: This question is not about latency compensation or synchronization between the client and the server. It is about asynchronous code execution in node.js (server only) vs. synchronous code execution in the browser (client only). Usually Meteor uses fibers to "simulate" synchronous behavior on the server. But this doesn't seem to be the case here wrt observers. I suspect there's a good reason for this which I ignore.

Comment: Yes I see you've edited the question to clarify this, could you provide the code you're using to show the conditions this occurs in?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in the [meteor-talk group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/MxrDzfi0sr8/7MMLalicCc4J). The corresponding code comment can be found [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js#L80):

```
// After making a write (with insert, update, remove), observers are
// notified asynchronously. If you want to receive a callback once all
// of the observer notifications have landed for your write, do the
// writes inside a write fence (set Meteor._CurrentWriteFence to a new
// _WriteFence, and then set a callback on the write fence.)
```

Just in case you wonder how that looks in practice - here's what I did (in coffeescript):

```
Future = __meteor_bootstrap__.require('fibers/future')
...
future = new Future
fence = new Meteor._WriteFence
fence.onAllCommitted ->
  fence.retire()
  future.ret()
result = Meteor._CurrentWriteFence.withValue fence, ->
  # do something that triggers observers
  ...
  return result
fence.arm()
future.wait() # This will return only /after/ all observers fired.
...
```

This is an undocumented feature and not guaranteed to work in the long run. So my question remains open in case the core team wants to describe an official workaround.